# How to determine what GPU is being used via command line Windows 10?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, gpu

I am trying to determine what GPU is being used (dedicated or integrated) via command line. I can run a benchmark program and read the output of that, but I am trying to figure it out from command line before I run the benchmark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Programs can choose which GPU to use, which is going to throw a wrench in your testing.

Comment: Are you able to provide a source for that claim?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that applications choose which GPU to use, but there is a helpful trick to detect this.

[GPUz](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) can show you GPU usage per GPU card. It can display memory usage and GPU load briefly, so that will help you determine if an application uses the dedicated or integrated GPU.

From a command line, that would may be possible with some deep WMI Data query, however, information on GPU-related syntax is not too easy to find.