# Determine what GPU is running through WMI

Tags: windows, python, gpu, wmi

I am trying to write a python script for to figure out which GPU (dedicated or integrated) is currently running. I have managed to make it work so far by running dxdiag and parsing the output for the mode of each gpu device, but this is taking way too long. Does anyone know how dxdiag gets this information? Is there a way to get the info through Windows management Instrument? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://superuser.com/questions/1087438/how-to-determine-what-gpu-is-being-used-via-command-line-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

WMI class Win32_VideoController has a properties named Availability can show the statues of the video Controller, but not all device will input values to it.

Try this command to list the result:

wmic path Win32_VideoController get Caption, Availability

In the result, 3 means full power. You can check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394512(v=vs.85).aspx for more information.

Meanwhile, you can consider to use WMIExplorer tool to save your time during find things in WMI. the download link: https://wmie.codeplex.com/